# CSS, absolutely position ontop of other layers with horizontal centering and fixed width

Tags: css

First, I wonder if anyone can even say that question title ten times fast.

This should be pretty easy. I've been googling around, and while there are a lot of tutorials on it, I'm having trouble grasping the idea overall. I've even looked at some other SO questions that *seem* related but I've not been able to make them work.

I have 3 layers. `header`, `menu`, `body`. The real application is much more complicated, of course. But for the sake of this question this is sufficient enough data.

The entire page itself fills `100% width`, but the content within each section will be fixed to `1024px` wide. This was easily done with the reknown `margin: 0 auto;` style. So that wasn't an issue.

Here is the trick. The middle layer, the `menu`. I want the menu to overlap the border between the header and the content. Now then, doing this was also not too hard. I just absolutely position the menu and kick it down by `100px` to get it to the right vertical alignment.

What I cannot seem to achieve is the `horizontal` alignment of the `1024px` block. I've included a light fiddle and an image of the expected output (**beware, jsfiddle's default preview pane is not 1024px wide, so it looks like it is working at first glance**)

## Update

Following the instructions at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157372/css-horizontal-centering-of-a-fixed-div) I was able to make it work. But it is only functioning in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/dE8xE/

Desired Output (colors exaggerated for emphasis and distinction)

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Why don't you just use something like `margin: 0 80px;`? http://jsfiddle.net/dE8xE/1/ Your content areas seems to be of fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#site-menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    display: block;
    width: 1024px;
```

/* everything is easy when you have fixed width */

```
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use percentage margins and width to achieve the effect you're going for?  Setting the z-index to something greater than those of the other sections will get it to float over them. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6xCfU/

```
margin: 10% 0 0 10%;
width: 80%;
z-index; 100;
```

Comment: Relative margin/padding never works as intended in conjunction with an absolute width/height, and vice versa. Compare a TV screen with an iPad: 10% of the first isn't even getting close to 10% of the second.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good idea, but as Rob points out it won't scale very well.

Comment: @Rob - You could use it with a min-width.