# horizontallly center table who's position is relative (width is responsive)

Tags: html, css, fixed

This is my HTML:

```
<div id='footer'>
    <table id='headerBar'>
        <tr>
        <td class='headerBarActualTd'><a href='/' class='headerBarIconLink'></a><a href='/' id='homeIcon'></a></td>
        <td class='headerBarSpacingTd'></td>
        <td class='headerBarActualTd'><a href='/username/' class='headerBarIconLink'></a><a href='/uesrname/' id='myProfileIcon'></a></td>
        <td class='headerBarSpacingTd'></td>
        <td class='headerBarActualTd'><a href='/settings/settingsPage/' class='headerBarIconLink'></a><a href='/' id='settingsIcon'></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
#footer table {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#headerBar {
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
#headerBar .headerBarActualTd {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
}

#headerBar .headerBarSpacingTd {
    padding: 10px;
}
.headerBarIconLink {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.headerBarIconLink:hover {
    border: 1px solid #5f9f9f; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I want to horizontally center my table while it is position (fixed) at the bottom of the screen. I've read a lot of posts (like this 
[CSS horizontal centering of a fixed div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157372/css-horizontal-centering-of-a-fixed-div) )

where the solution involves making the margin-left half of the width, however, I do not know the width since my width will be responsive and will depend on the users screen. Is there a way to make the table horizontally centered without knowing the exact width?

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p3W4s/

(if you increase the screen of the actual fiddle, you'll see that the table is not aligned in the center).

Comment: `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

Comment: @Sebastien apply that CSS to the table? It doesn't seem to work if I give the table a margin-left and a margin-right of auto: http://jsfiddle.net/6E2G9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the whole width 100%, and put your table inside with margin: 0 auto, 
will align everything center.  and just change the yellow background to transparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/yUNuV/

html
    
        
    
css

```
.fixed {
width:100%;
height:40px;
background:yellow;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
.center {
margin:0 auto;
width: 50%;
height:inherit;
background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will allow you to see all three centered. I also added the padding since the last table was running off the screen.

```
#footer table {
position: fixed;
padding-right: 18px;
bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: hm can you give me a fiddle? It doesn't seem to work over here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6E2G9/ Once I extend the screen of the fiddle, the table doesn't seem to be in the middle. Instead, it looks like it is aligned to the left.

Comment: really? it looks like it's centered to me.