# Center a fixed draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a **fixed** `div` which I am trying to center vertically and horizontally. Yes, I know there are **many** question and tutorials to perform this. I checked and followed the instructions. Here's one that I implemented:

```
#draggable {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Now, I also want the `div` to be draggable. So it should start off at the center of the screen, then the user will have an option to drag it.

The problem is, when you start dragging it, the `div` suddenly moves higher. How can I center a fixed, draggable `div`?

#### JSFiddle

```js
$('#draggable').draggable();
```

```css
body {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url("http://www.freevector.com/site_media/preview_images/FreeVector-Square-Patterns-Set.jpg");
}
#draggable {
  background-color: red;
  color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="draggable">Drag Me!</div>
```

**Edit** I updated the examples. `draggable` doesn't have a set height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use draggable start method to modify css.

```
$('#draggable').draggable({ start: function() {

$(this).css({transform: "none", top: $(this).offset().top+"px", left:$(this).offset().left+"px"});

} });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y2ehtjsu/4/

This gets current position calculated by browser and converts it into normal pixel value, on draggable start. 
If you are using draggable I sugggest you to familiarize yourself with this:  http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If you try dragging it off screen, (meaning, dragging off screen so that it should scroll,) `draggable` goes way off the cursor position. The more you drag, the more it goes away. How can I fix that?

Comment: It seems like jquery uses position relative to the page instead of relative to the browser window. You could use drag method to update the position of the helper properly. On drag start calculate the initial distance between top left edgde of the element and mouse pointer, then use drag method to update the position to mouse position + the initial distance.

Comment: Also, how can I make the position a percentage? This way, when the browser gets resized, `draggable` will maintain its position.

Answer (score 3):

Improving on Maciej Krawczyk's answer.

You could put `transform` in a separate class (call it `centered`) and remove the class when user starts to drag. After all, usually the purpose of dragging something is to permanently change its position. This means you need the centering `transform` to work only once (when the `div` is first shown). You most probably do not need it to work neither when user drags the `div` nor at any later stage.

http://jsfiddle.net/y2ehtjsu/8/

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the draggable code doesn't seem to properly handle translated element positions.  The easy way to fix that is to just remove the translate and start your position at 40%/40% which will center it since the width/height is 20%.

```js
$('#draggable').draggable();
```

```css
body {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url("http://www.freevector.com/site_media/preview_images/FreeVector-Square-Patterns-Set.jpg");
}
#draggable {
  background-color: red;
  color: lightblue;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="draggable">Drag Me!</div>
```

Comment: An alternative and modern way of centering an element horizontally and vertically is to use the css flexbox.  I keep referring to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ as there are a lot of parameters, but it works beautifully.

Comment: `draggable` doesn't have a height. I know it does in the examples, but it was a mistake.