# Horizontal center a select in a div with Bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I cannot figure out how to center my select in my div.

```
<!--PAGE CONTENT-->
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">       
    <div class="row text-center justify-content-center"  style="border: 1px solid red;">   
        <!--SELECT-->
        <select id="selectList" style="width: 200px;">
            <option></option>
            <option value="attendance">Närvaro</option>
            <option value="students">Elever</option>
        </select>
        <hr>

        <!--Js Content-->
        <div id="jsContent"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I tried difrent bootstrap classes with no result.

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/o9b17p2d/38/

**UPDATE**
When searching for an answer to this question i only found "VERTICAL" centering. That why i think this question should stay with the Horizontal in the Topic!

Comment: You have `hr` and one more div element in that row also. So what you mean by center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select and other content should be inside a Bootstrap `col-*`, not place directly in the `row`. Just use `mx-auto` to center.

https://www.codeply.com/go/L2IUUMbdgm

```
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">       
        <div class="row text-center justify-content-center"  style="border: 1px solid red;">   
        <div class="col-12">

            <!--SELECT-->
            <select id="selectList" class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
                <option></option>
                <option value="attendance">Närvaro</option>
                <option value="students">Elever</option>
            </select>
            <hr>

            <!--Js Content-->
            <div id="jsContent"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're using Bootstrap 4, you can use flex to center elements. It's really clean.

You need to add `d-flex` to the container, and keep the `justify-content-center`

I added a wrapper inside the `row` element, so that all three elements (`hr`, `select` and `div.jsContent`) are centered.

```
<!--PAGE CONTENT-->
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">       
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center"  style="border: 1px solid red;">   
        <!--SELECT-->
        <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
          <select id="selectList" style="width: 200px;">
              <option></option>
              <option value="attendance">Närvaro</option>
              <option value="students">Elever</option>
          </select>
          <hr>

          <!--Js Content-->
          <div id="jsContent">
            JS Content
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramses_lopezs/kwshdgg6/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157372/css-horizontal-centering-of-a-fixed-div):

```
<!--PAGE CONTENT-->
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">       
    <div class="row text-center justify-content-center"  style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%; position: absolute">   
        <!--SELECT-->
        <select id="selectList" style="width: 200px; position: relative; left: 50%; margin-left: -100px; ">
            <option></option>
            <option value="attendance">Närvaro</option>
            <option value="students">Elever</option>
        </select>
        <hr>

        <!--Js Content-->
        <div id="jsContent"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9b17p2d/42/)**

Comment: Is it recommended or good practice to use negative margin values?

Comment: @PriyaPayyavula I wouln't say it's best practice. But I'm not an expert for that.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Thank you for your attempt to clarify it.